# Выборка из базы Oracle

Tags: oracle

С oracle незнаком, только начинаю изучать.
Вот запрос, который выбирает абонентов и базы

```
SELECT DISTINCT ss_login, ct_mcode, ct_id
FROM inac.start_stop, inac.services, inac.cities0, inac.services_param
WHERE inac.services.s_f_vpdn = 1
AND inac.services.s_f_ppp = 0
AND inac.start_stop.ss_service = inac.services.s_id
AND inac.services.s_city = inac.cities0.ct_id
AND ct_mcode = 'RND'
AND ss_start <= to_date('01.11.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND (ss_stop >= to_date('01.10.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') or ss_stop is null)
```

нужно чтобы еще в выборку попала информация о том что абонент конвергентный или нет

связь таблиц inac.start_stop.ss_service = inac.services_param.id_service
условие что абонент конвергентный inac.services_param.param_name = 'BILL_TYPE' и  inac.services_param.param_number = 3

Попробовал вот так

```
SELECT DISTINCT ss_login, ct_mcode, ct_id, param_name, param_number
CASE 
WHEN param_name = 'BILL_TYPE' and param_number = 3
THEN 'Да'
ELSE 'Нет' end
FROM inac.start_stop, inac.services, inac.cities0, inac.services_param
WHERE inac.services.s_f_vpdn = 1
AND inac.services.s_f_ppp = 0
AND inac.start_stop.ss_service = inac.services.s_id
AND inac.services.s_city = inac.cities0.ct_id
AND inac.start_stop.ss_service = inac.services_param.id_service
AND ct_mcode = 'RND'
AND ss_start <= to_date('01.11.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND (ss_stop >= to_date('01.10.2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') or ss_stop is null)
```

Ошибка
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: В первой строке, после ` param_number` запятую поставьте

Comment: Но я не уверен что это даст нужный результат. Если в выборке будут такие строки для которых для одного логина может быть и "да" и "нет" - то будут на выходе две строки. Но не видя всю структуру ваших таблиц это сказать невозможно.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо добрый человек, надо внимательнее читать примеры.

Comment: @thecoder, попробуйте использовать `join`-ы. С ними куда читабельнее запросы получаются, ИМХО.

Comment: @4per, какой пример заказчик дал такие пытаюсь пробовать. Чем они читабельнее будут?

Comment: @thecoder, условия соединения будут отделены от условий фильтрации. Добавьте еще лесенку и ваша ошибка уже начнёт бросаться в глаза.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется билли пропустил запятую. Она должна стоять перед CASE ,в конце первой строчки